# PHP - pass an argument and pre-transform it in the same line?

Tags: php, arguments, reduce, assign

I know it's a weird question, but I have a static method declared like this:

```
public static function getCountForTypesByModificationYear($year, $filter = null) {
    $filter["modification year"] = $year;
    return self::getCountForTypes($filter);
}
```

It takes an argument (a year) and, optionally, an associative array with additional filtering options. The first line ensures the `$filter` array has just one `modification year` key (which I'm providing as the first argument) and the second one fires the method with the SQL query for counting potential results for the selected filters.

They're pretty self-explanatory and simple for my purposes, but I'm trying to guess if there is a way to make these two lines into a one-liner **WITHOUT** resorting to functions like `array_merge_recursive()` or `call_user_func()`.

Can this be reduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is to make it in one line you can try the below:

```
public static function getCountForTypesByModificationYear($year, $filter = null) {
    return self::getCountForTypes(($filter["modification year"] = $year) ? $filter : null);
}
```

However, Im not sure if its will be better performance wise.

Alternatively you can also do,

```
return self::getCountForTypes(["modification year" => $year] + $filter);
```

Comment: I'm ok with the performance it has right now so I'll try the second one. Thanks! :)

Comment: The second approach is what I needed. It's almost 5% faster for all test cases!. I owe you a beer ;)

Comment: Im glad I could help, Cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only by some function call, like array_merge function.
Expression like `($filter['xx']=123)` return right side operand value

```
public static function getCountForTypesByModificationYear($year, $filter = null) 
{
    return self::getCountForTypes(array_merge($filter,["modification_yer"=> $year]));
}
```

Also in your example, if you do not use type-hint 'array' and set `$filter` default value to null - you should ensure that `$filter` is array

```
public static function getCountForTypesByModificationYear($year, $filter = null) 
{
    if( !is_array($filter) ) throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
    return self::getCountForTypes(array_merge($filter,["modification_yer"=> $year]));
}
```